# Does TFS/Azure DevOps on premise have integration with okta for SSO?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, okta, tfvc

We are using TFS 2017 update 3 on prem, and planning an upgrade to TFS 2019 on prem.
Would like to know if we can integrate tfs access into Okta for any of these versions.

Answer (score 1):

TFS only uses Active Directory authentication (NTLM//Kerberos).You could take a look at this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/team-foundation-server-2017-and-kerberos-authentication/) for more detail authentication.

I don’t find any official article about TFS/Azure DevOps system integration with third-party SSO.